# descending order is not working properly c programming

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

the ascending order is doing a great job. But when I enter a number different than one, it should call the descending order, which I think is well defined. Yet I have a random sorting..

```
  #include<stdio.h>

void sort(int b[], int size, int (*upordown)(int a, int b));
void swap(int *elt1, int *elt2);
int ascending(int a, int b);
int descending(int a, int b);
main()
{
int size =8;
int order,a[size],i;
fprintf(stdout, "please enter a sequence of numbers you wish to sort:\n");
for(i =0; i<size; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
printf("\n please enter 1 for ascending order or 2 for descending order");
scanf("%d", &order);
if(order == 1)
{
    sort(a, size, ascending);
}
else 
{
    sort(a, size, descending);
}
printf("Here is the new re arranged array: \n");
for(i =0; i<size; i++)
{
    printf("%d\t", a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}

void sort(int b[], int size, int (*upordown)(int a, int b))
{
int pass, j;
for(pass =0; pass< size;pass++)
{
    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if((*upordown)(b[j], b[j+1]))
        {
            swap(&b[j], &b[j+1]);
        }
    }
}

}

void swap(int *elt1, int *elt2)
{
int hold;
if(*elt1 > *elt2)
{
    hold = *elt1;
    *elt1 = *elt2;
    *elt2 = hold;
}

}

int ascending(int a, int b)
{
return b<a;
}
int descending(int a, int b)
{
return b>a;
}
```

Comment: You have an extra > check in `swap` which is probably unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your swap function is incorrect. It should simply swap its passed parameters:

```
void swap(int *elt1, int *elt2)
{
    int hold;
    hold = *elt1;
    *elt1 = *elt2;
    *elt2 = hold;
}
```

It should not contain a comparison.